# How to get the function definition in a python file without import libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a file test.py with the content. The file structure is defined below. I dont have control over the structure of the file.

```
import *some python libraries*

def my_function:
    content = "This is my function"
    return content
```

I would like to write a code that would read this python file and return the return value for the function my_function that is "This is my function"

I can do this using importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader but it import *some python libraries* which I don't want. Is there any way I can achieve this. Regex is one solution but it could be an issue if the variable name changes. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Put `my_function` in a module that doesn't import the other libraries.

Comment: that's not a solution. I don't have control over the content of the python files.

Comment: Yes it is. Updated the question.

Comment: Does the removal of that unwanted import make `test.py` un-compilable? That is, are there any variables or functions in `test.py` that rely on the unwanted library?

Comment: @blhsing yes. I cannot remove it from the file.

Comment: I see, but at least `my_function` itself does not rely on the unwanted library. Right?

Comment: Yes. That is a good tip. Remove all the imports from the file and add parse only the rest of the file to SourceFileLoader. I can test it out.

Comment: Does it really matter if you some libraries you don't care about get imported? Short of manually parsing the file, you can't do what you want.

Comment: Sounds like an x-y problem. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Well that isn't actually what I was hinting at because if `my_function` is all you want, it is much easier to extract just `my_function` alone from the module than to remove the unwanted library and all the codes that depend on the library.

Comment: @blhsing can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I've elaborated it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing that `my_function` has no other dependencies within `test.py`, you can use `ast.parse` to parse the file into an AST tree, use `ast.walk` to iterate through the nodes, look for a `FunctionDef` node whose `name` is `my_function`, compile the node after adding a `Module` node around it, and execute the compiled code object so that the function can be made available in your current namespace:

```
import pkgutil
import ast
with open(pkgutil.get_loader('test').get_filename()) as file:
    for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(file.read())):
        if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef) and node.name == 'my_function':
            exec(compile(ast.Module(body=[node]), '', 'exec'))
```

so that if `test.py` contains:

```
import foobar
def my_function(a):
    return a + 1
bomb = 0 / 0 # bad stuff. importing this will raise an exception.
```

after running the example code above, `my_function(2)` will return: `3`